# Clamping 9-volt input to 8-volt?

Tags: arduino-mini

Have a DFRobot Arduino Pro Mini.

Seems odd to me, but according to their specs the voltage regulator on board cannot handle more than 8-volt input. I can find no documentation, or have they answered me concerning what specific regulator they use on the board.

I would like to be able to run this board from a 9-volt battery. What is the best / most eloquent way to do this, keeping the smallest component footprint for a home etched board ?

An additional regulator ?? Could a diode clamp the voltage down ?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The schematic tells you exactly which regulator they use. They also have a (broken) link to its datasheet on the page.

Comment: And the regulator's a piece of crap. I'd be embarrassed to spec a part like that for a project.

Comment: Thank you, Ignacio.  This is the 1st one I've purchased.  It seems (at least so far) it works OK on USB power...  But why a regulator that can't at least handle a 9-volt battery ??

But, again...  What is the best way to clamp a 9-volt battery to 8-volt ?

Comment: Haven't found that schematic...  Exactly what regulator are they using ?

Comment: You're almost better off getting a small 1S Li-ion/Lipo battery and strapping it to a boost regulator and stuffing it into the 5V connection.

Comment: https://www.dfrobot.com/product-696.html

Comment: So...  Can I assume by your comments that their design has a lot to be desired ??

Comment: Their design is bog-standard '328P stuff, except for that awful, awful regulator.

Comment: i would use a cheap (~$1) DC-DC buck converter from ebay to drop it to 5v for max battery life. voltages above the minimum input for the regulator are wasted as heat at the same rate as your real parts.

Comment: I second dandavis; use a buck converter (not a linear one). Like the MP1584 based boards. Very small and cheap

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure first that their claim ofb8v max is right. Look up the datasheet for the regulator and go from there.

If you have to go with 8v max, put a diode or two, or an led in serial should work most of the time.

For those where such an approach doesn't work, wire up an external regulator.